# Rate of Growth precise definition for function

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Could give me precise definition in simple english what really `Rate of Growth` means when we talking about some function `T(n)`? And how should I denoted it?

As I understand, if we have a functions like:

$$T1(n) = 6*n^2 + 5*n + 123$$
  $$T2(n) = 2^n + 3*n^2 + 7 * n! + 5*n$$

Then, `Rate of Growth` will be equal to (I don't know how to denote it):

$$ T1RateOfGrowth = n^2 $$
$$ T2RateOfGrowth = n! $$

Comment: We can say that two functions have the same rate of grows if their quotient is bounded away from $0$ and $\infty$ for $n\gg 0$. Then to speak of *the* rate of growth of a given function would mean to pick a specific member/representative from the equivalence class of functions having same rate of growth. Sometimes, good representatives suggest themselves, such as $n\mapsto n^k$, but the choice of representative may not always be obvious.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you! Could you please explain in details what do you mean by `equivalence class of functions having same rate of growth` (with example, please)?

Comment: For $f,g\colon\Bbb N\to \Bbb R$, we can define $f\sim g:\Leftrightarrow \exists m\in\Bbb N,\exists c>0, \forall n>m, \frac1cg(n)\le f(n)\le cg(n)$. One verifies that this is an equivalence relation. With this definition, we can verify $T_1\sim(n\mapsto n^2)$ by picking $m=20$ and $c=10$, for example. Similarly, $T_1\sim (n\mapsto 3n^2+\sin n+5)$ or $T_1\sim (n\mapsto{n\choose 2})$, but for somewhat obvious reasons $n\mapsto n^2$ is our favourite representative of the equivalence class.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Does it means that `Rate of Growth` shows how fast function's value growth to infinity, when n tends towards infinity?